# linux shell command in Perl program

Tags: perl, mysql, services

Hi friends here is some issue I want to write a script that restarts server which is in stopped status. Here I am using my MySQL server in future if it is in stopped status then it will be restarted with script. I am using `perl` language and my code is:

GNU nano 2.2.6              File: service.pl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

if  (system("service mysql status") =~ "start/running") {
    system("service mysql start");
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
mysql stop/waiting
```

but here i want output that if server in stop status it will be in start status

How to resolve it?

Comment: You are checking if the status is `"start/running"`. Shouldn't you negate the check?

Comment: condition is if not start/running  then  system("service mysql start"); start the server. any example please share , i am new in this field.

Comment: See the answer I wrote to explain what I meant and what you asked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a *find "start/running" or something similar* which is better formatted as

```
if (system("service mysql status") =~ /start\/running/)
```

Next thing is that you will match the return code of the `system` command instead of the output. Use backticks (`) instead:

```
if (`service mysql status` =~ /start\/running/)
```

There is no `not` in this condition as you stated in your comment. You want the `not` you will have to use `!~` instead of `=~`:

```
if (`service mysql status` !~ /start\/running/)
```

This will result in the following code to have `mysql` (re)started if it is in another state than `start/running`:

```
if (`service mysql status` !~ /start\/running/) {
    `service mysql restart`;
}
```

**Note**: You will need to execute your perl script as a user which is allowed to start/stop services, i.e. `root`

See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Simple-word-matching for reference.

Comment: Dear Sir, output of this program is "mysql stop/waiting" it show only status of mysql    . i want if mysql server in stop status and when i run this program then program restart the stop mysql server

Comment: Thanks you,  sir your suggestion is working i am thank full for this help. and sir provide me link where i learn perl to easy.

Comment: https://www.perl.org/learn.html is a good start for `perl` documentation and examples. Good luck learning `perl`